# Bash Merge 2 files conditionally

Tags: bash, nested-loops, cat

I'm trying to merge the second field of the csv with all the id's in the diff file. codes.csv has 2 fields: ID,Description. I keep getting an error on the second `cat`.

```
cat: codes.cvs: No such file or directory.
```

The file does exist and I'm running the script from the same directory as codes.csv.

```
for i in `cat diff.txt`;
do
 for j in `cat codes.cvs`;
 do
  id = `sed  "$j"`;
  desc = `sed "?=$j"`;
  if [$i == $id]
  then
    echo "$id $desc"
  fi
 done;
done;
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Good luck with this... Better use a real programming language and a CSV parser

Comment: Are you sure that `codes.cvs` should not be `codes.csv`?

Comment: Wow.... That is extremely frustrating. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple typo. `codes.cvs` should be `codes.csv` as you indicated the name was everywhere else.

```
for i in `cat diff.txt`;
do
 for j in `cat codes.csv`;
 do
  id=`sed  "$j"`;
  desc=`sed "?=$j"`;
  if [ $i == $id ]
  then
    echo "$id $desc"
  fi
 done;
done;
```

Comment: Don't you need spaces after the `test` command? i.e. the `[`. And there should be no spaces before and after the `=`

Comment: I do believe so... Updated.

Comment: The "=" is equivalent to "==". See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html